# Ajax never complete

Tags: php, android, jquery, cordova, ionic-framework

This code in my Server.php

```
$api = new Api('xdf', 'dfgd');
$payment = $api->payment->fetch($paymentId);
$capture=$payment->capture(array('amount' => $payment['amount']));
```

This code in my Ionic controller

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.com/payment/create',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization_Token', 'fcfbe6a4af54805b2');
    },
    data: {
        UserId: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("CurrentUser")).UserId,
        DealId: $stateParams.id,
        PaymentId: paymentId
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log('sfhkjfgjkdfgkhdfhk')
    },

})
```

Problem is I tested this code in my system browser it works well and it works well in android kitkat. But in android 4.2 and above Ajax request never end.That means NO success and No error return from server. If I comment RAZORPAY function Ajax request run well.

Comment: use the whole url (put http before the url)

Comment: it just a example.it is not real problem.

Comment: are you using https or http?

Comment: and what do you mean by "If I comment RAZORPAY function Ajax request run well"?

Comment: if remove all rezorpay api code ,PHP page will return proper response to AJAX.

Comment: and the razorpay is on your server or on your client? you didn't show any razorpay code. Anyway, if you say it work without it and doesn't work with it, the problem is the razorpay code, not the ajax call. Search about remote debuging of apps to find the problem

Comment: Server.php get all razorpay code. If i call Server.php from android kitkat Server.php responses properly . But from android 4.2 it not send any response

Comment: @ABIRAMAN can you show me an example of how to integrate razorpay in our ionc app?

Comment: Now razorpay cordova plugin is available .Use plugin for integration.